# Probability and variance of random variable question

Tags: probability, statistics

**Q: 90% of dogs recognise owner's voice. A random sample of 20 dogs is taken. 
a) find prob that all 20 dogs recognise owner's voice.
b) X = number of dogs that don't recognise owner's voice. Find the variance of X.**

**For part a**, I did 0.9^20 to get 12.158% of dogs recognising owner's voice.

**For part b**, I looked at the number of dogs that recognise owner's voice (.9 x 20) = 18, which means that 2 dogs don't recognise the owner's voice?

If 2 is correct, then I'm aware of this formula to find variance:

nP(1-P)

But, I'm not sure which values to plug into the formula. Could anybody help? Would it be 20 x .1 x (1-.1)? .1 representing the 10% chance of not recognising the owner's voice.

Comment: Look up "variance of a binomial distribution"

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up. Could you clarify whether 2 is correct to represent the number of dogs that can't recognise their owner? @Paul

Answer (score 1):

a) The random variable follows binomial distribution with $n=20$ and $p=0.9$ (being the probability of success, that is, of a dog recognizing owner's voice) That gives $P(20)=0.12518$ as you said.
b) The random variable $X$ follows a binomial distribution but with $p=0.1$, which is "the probability of success of a failure". The variance of such distribution is $np(1-p)=1.8$

By the way, the calculation $ 0.9 \cdot 20= 18$ gives the **expected** number of dogs that will recognize de voice in s sample of 20. The actual number may vary (if not, it wouldn't be random ...)

Comment: Right, so basically the question doesn't require me to find an actual value for the number of dogs that can't recognise their owner's voices, just the variance? Also, just to check, np(1-p) = 1.8 for me, not 10.8. Is 1.8 correct? Thanks!

Comment: OK, typo corrected, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on the binomial distribution which is:
$P(k) = \binom nk \theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$. This is a probability distribution. Using that, you can calculate the expected value as well as the variance. Simply follow the the definition of those.

Note that $\theta=0.1$ in your case as you want to count dogs that were not able to recognize the voice.

Comment: Thanks, but why 0.9 and not 0.1? For part b, I'm looking for the dogs that can't recognise their owners, which is 10%?

Comment: Indeed-> modified.